# MVC 5 - Create Conditional Razor Output

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following Razor code, which is working correctly.

```
<div>
    <p class="text-info">Tour Durations</p>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.AdvertiserTourDuration.Count; i++)
    {
        <span>
            @Model.AdvertiserTourDuration[i].TourDuration.Description
        </span>
    }
</div>
```

But, I would like to separate each tour duration with a '/' character. But, of course, I don't want to start or end the list with a '/' character. So I thought I would attempt to place the '/' character before the span, but only if i > 0 (because I don't want to start the list with a '/' character). I can't seem to get the code right, because the code I write to do this ends up rendered in the browser.

Comment: What do you mean the code ends up in the output? Do you mean once rendered you see `@Model.AdvertiserTourDuration[i].TourDuration.Description` instead of an actual description?

Comment: @Adrian - No, read my post a little more carefully. The code I have posted is working correctly, as I've stated. What I said was that when I add code to output a '/', but only if i > 0, the code I write to do this actually gets output to the browser. So I don't know how to write the conditional code so the code itself doesn't get outputted to the browser.

Comment: It would help if you wrote down the code that wasn't working instead of the code that is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you're doing wrong since you did not post the culprit code but give this a shot.

```
<div>
<p class="text-info">Tour Durations</p>
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.AdvertiserTourDuration.Count; i++)
{
    if (i > 0)
    {
        <text>/</text>
    }
    <span>
        @Model.AdvertiserTourDuration[i].TourDuration.Description
    </span>
}
```